# WMTS layer from GetCapabilities does not work in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wmts, getcapabilities

I am trying to create functionality where I consume GetCapabilities data from several services and use that data to create layers with OpenLayers 6. However some GetCapabilities work and some don't.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        
        .box {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .box-header {
            flex: 0 1 40px;
            padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
        }
        .box-content {
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
        }
        .box-footer {
            flex: 0 1 40px;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #mapConainer {
            border: 1px solid grey;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
    </style>
    <title>GetCapabilities Test</title>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.15/proj4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.11.0/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
            <span>Description: GetCapabilities</span>
        </div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <div id="mapConainer"/>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        const LKS_SRS = 'EPSG:3346';
        const LKS_EXTENT_ARRAY = [307558.9491752772, 5970000.0, 685218.1236202281, 6264605.2051798785];
        const GET_CAPABILITES_XML_PARSER = new ol.format.WMTSCapabilities();

        var olMap;
        
        window.onload = (event) => {
            defineEPSG3346InProj4();
            
            var options = {
                target: 'mapConainer',
                view: new ol.View({
                    enableRotation: false,
                    projection: LKS_SRS,
                    extent: LKS_EXTENT_ARRAY,
                    center: [358984.04, 6207403.26],
                    zoom: 5,
                }),
                controls: []
            };


            olMap = new ol.Map(options);
            
            // does not work
            var url = "https://www.geoportal.lt/arcgis/rest/services/geoportal_teikeju/ZUIKVC_paseliai/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml";
            // works
            //url = "https://beta.maps.lt/arcgis/rest/services/mapslt_ortofoto_wmerc/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml";
            
            getWMTSCapabilitiesAndCreateLayer(url, null, (layer) => {
                olMap.addLayer(layer);
            });
        };
                

        function defineEPSG3346InProj4() {
            const LKS_PROJECTION_DEC = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=24 +k=0.9998+x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs';
            proj4.defs(LKS_SRS, LKS_PROJECTION_DEC);
            ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
            ol.proj.get(LKS_SRS).setExtent(LKS_EXTENT_ARRAY);
        };  

        function getWMTSCapabilitiesAndCreateLayer(url, layerIdentifier, callback) {
            fetch(url)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.text();
                })
                .then(function (text) {
                    callback(parseGetCapabilitiesXMLAndCreateWMTSLayer(text, layerIdentifier));
                });
        };

        function parseGetCapabilitiesXMLAndCreateWMTSLayer(getCapabilitiesXML, layerIdentifier) {   
            var parsedXML = GET_CAPABILITES_XML_PARSER.read(getCapabilitiesXML);
            
            if (!layerIdentifier) {
                layerIdentifier = parsedXML.Contents.Layer[0].Identifier;
            }
            
            var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(parsedXML, {
                layer: layerIdentifier
            });
            
            return createWMTSLayerWithOptions(options);
        };

        function createWMTSLayerWithOptions(options) {              
            return layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.WMTS(options)
            });
        };
    </script>
</body></html>
```

Edit this place to switch between not working example and working one:

```
// does not work
var url = "https://www.geoportal.lt/arcgis/rest/services/geoportal_teikeju/ZUIKVC_paseliai/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml";
// works
//url = "https://beta.maps.lt/arcgis/rest/services/mapslt_ortofoto_wmerc/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml";
```

Comment: Did not see that the uploads on that site are deleted after first download. I have compiled all the code into single file-script now

Answer (score 1):

For some reason WMTS options created from capabilities do not work for that site. Here's how they look like (created with OL 6.3.0 for readability):

```
{
  "urls": [
      "http://www.geoportal.lt/arcgis/rest/services/geoportal_teikeju/ZUIKVC_paseliai/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/geoportal_teikeju_ZUIKVC_paseliai/{Style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}.png"
  ],
  "layer": "geoportal_teikeju_ZUIKVC_paseliai",
  "matrixSet": "default028mm",
  "format": "image/png",
  "projection": {
      "code_": "EPSG:3346",
      "units_": "m",
      "extent_": [
          307558.9491752772,
          5970000,
          685218.1236202281,
          6264605.2051798785
      ],
      "worldExtent_": null,
      "axisOrientation_": "enu",
      "global_": false,
      "canWrapX_": false,
      "defaultTileGrid_": null
  },
  "requestEncoding": "REST",
  "tileGrid": {
      "minZoom": 0,
      "resolutions_": [
          529.1677250020501,
          264.58386250102507,
          132.29193125051253,
          66.14596562525627,
          26.458386250102503,
          13.229193125051252,
          6.614596562525626,
          2.6458386250102506,
          1.3229193125051253
      ],
      "maxZoom": 8,
      "origin_": null,
      "origins_": [
          [
              10000100,
              -5122000
          ],
          [
              10000100,
              -5122000
          ],
          [
              10000100,
              -5122000
          ],
          [
              10000100,
              -5122000
          ],
          [
              10000100,
              -5122000
          ],
          [
              10000100,
              -5122000
          ],
          [
              10000100,
              -5122000
          ],
          [
              10000100,
              -5122000
          ],
          [
              10000100,
              -5122000
          ]
      ],
      "tileSizes_": [
          256,
          256,
          256,
          256,
          256,
          256,
          256,
          256,
          256
      ],
      "tileSize_": null,
      "extent_": [
          10000100,
          -9186008.128015745,
          15825178.316822568,
          -5122000
      ],
      "fullTileRanges_": [
          {
              "minX": 0,
              "maxX": 42,
              "minY": 0,
              "maxY": 29
          },
          {
              "minX": 0,
              "maxX": 85,
              "minY": 0,
              "maxY": 59
          },
          {
              "minX": 0,
              "maxX": 171,
              "minY": 0,
              "maxY": 118
          },
          {
              "minX": 0,
              "maxX": 342,
              "minY": 0,
              "maxY": 237
          },
          {
              "minX": 0,
              "maxX": 856,
              "minY": 0,
              "maxY": 594
          },
          {
              "minX": 0,
              "maxX": 1713,
              "minY": 0,
              "maxY": 1188
          },
          {
              "minX": 0,
              "maxX": 3426,
              "minY": 0,
              "maxY": 2377
          },
          {
              "minX": 0,
              "maxX": 8566,
              "minY": 0,
              "maxY": 5944
          },
          {
              "minX": 0,
              "maxX": 17132,
              "minY": 0,
              "maxY": 11888
          }
      ],
      "tmpSize_": [
          0,
          0
      ],
      "matrixIds_": [
          "0",
          "1",
          "2",
          "3",
          "4",
          "5",
          "6",
          "7",
          "8"
      ]
  },
  "style": "default",
  "dimensions": {},
  "wrapX": false
}
```

Since I'm not WMTS expert, I didn't go into details why this does not work. I just tried my choice of options, and it worked:

```
var layer = createWMTSLayerWithOptions({
  url: 'https://www.geoportal.lt/arcgis/rest/services/geoportal_teikeju/ZUIKVC_paseliai/MapServer/WMTS',
  layer: "geoportal_teikeju_ZUIKVC_paseliai",
  matrixSet: "default028mm",
  format: "image/png",
  projection: LKS_SRS,
  tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
    origin: [-5122600.0, 10000100],
    extent: LKS_EXTENT_ARRAY,
    tileSize: 256,
    resolutions: [529.1677250021168, 264.5838625010584, 132.2919312505292, 66.1459656252646, 26.458386250105836, 13.229193125052918, 6.614596562526459, 2.6458386250105836, 1.3229193125052918],
    matrixIds: ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
  }),
});
olMap.addLayer(layer);
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: I know I can make the layer work when I define layer parameters by hand (I had to do that before) but that beats the purpose of using GetCapabilities to create layers automatically.

Comment: You didn't include that info in the question.

Comment: Because question is about using/consuming GetCapabilities and not about creating a layer by hand:)

Comment: Sorry, but the person answering cannot read your mind and guess you already tried it by hand. If you would include that info, I wouldn't loose my time by trying it by hand.